# Correct inheritance in spring data repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to implement custom repository class annotated with `@Repository` which should inherit another class which is annotated `@Repository` as well.

What is correct implementation of that usecase? Can directly inherit that class and add `@Repository` to main, or there is another best practice? Actually I have problem when I have defined

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.foo.repositories", "com.example.bar.repositories" }
```

in `@Configuration` class in root it doesn't scan my repositories and I can't autowire it.

here is sample of my repository class:

parent repository (third party class):

```
@Repository
public abstract class ParentRepository {
  // ...
}
```

interface and impl class which are in package `com.example.foo.repositories`:

```
public interface IFooRepository {
   Foo getFoo();
}

@Repository
public class FooRepository extends ParentRepository implements IFooRepository {
   Foo getFoo() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Do you have idea how to fix it and make possible to autowire IFooRepository ? 
Thank you in advice.

EDIT:

I find out green bean next to @EnableJpaRepositories and when I click on the bean it redirects me to bar repository, and doesn't show FooRepository Bean. I don't understand because both repositories are identical implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc for jpa repositories

> In the preceding example, Spring is instructed to scan com.acme.repositories and all its subpackages for interfaces extending Repository or one of its subinterfaces. For each interface found, the infrastructure registers the persistence technology-specific FactoryBean to create the appropriate proxies that handle invocations of the query methods.
>    [see](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances)

So basicly `@EnableJpaRepositories` - is the same as xml configuration from the link - it instructs to find classes that extending `Repository`. In you example you have `@Repository` annotation - that instructs Spring to translate exceptions. You should includ `"com.example.foo.repositories", "com.example.bar.repositories"` into components scan. Try `@ComponentScan` annotation [see](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

Comment: Thank it helps, but I am not sure if I understand. I checked java docs for @EnableJpaRepositories and there is written "Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default." It should also scan repositories  or not?

Comment: @Denis Stephanov - this means that by default Spring will scan on the packe where your configuration class with `@EnableJpaRepositories` is located

Comment: So when I add it into spring module which Spring doesn't scan repositories by packages into that annotation but ComponentScan did?

Comment: @Denis Stephanov ComponentScan is scanning for components with different stereotypes like `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller` or `@Repository` - in you case you want component `@Repository`. `@EnableJpaRepositories` is scanning for classes inherited from spring `Repository` class by default it scans package of configuration class on which you set `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `@Primary` annotation to your custom repository should autowire it into another class whenever possible by default, even if there are other valid beans for the autowire.

Comment: I tried it and doesn't work :/ check my updated question please.